WebStorm creates empty attribute value when inserting a template
How to stop WebStorm/PHPStorm from including the unnecessary empty attribute value in the inserted template?
For example, when I type v3c, instead of this:
<script setup lang="ts">

It makes this:
<script setup="" lang="ts">

Notice the unnecessary assignment and quotes (="") - I need to disable them to avoid having to remove them each time manually.

Go to  Editor -> Live Templates -> Vue -> v3c and uncheck "Reformat according to style".

